# Receiving error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'interactions' trying to run interactions.py

Tags: python-3.x

While trying to run a discord bot, after downloading interactions.py, I am reached by the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Client' from 'interactions'`. Any ideas on how to fix this? All other `from XXXXX import XXXXX` have worked, and I'm not sure what is happening.

I have tried moving the line of code `from interactions import Client` above the point in code where using `interactions.Client(token="XXXXX")` is. However, this has not changed anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.